# how to get a service from angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I have a variable that contains my angular app

(was instantiated with:)

```
var app = angular.module('app', [...]);
```

And I want to get the `$timeout` service.

How can I get this service from the it?

I want something like:

```
var timeout = app.getService('$timeout');
```

or

```
app.something('$imeout', function($timeout) {
    ...
} // like controller() does
```

Where I want to use it:

```
define([], function () { // I can import my angular module 'app', or 'angular'
    return {
        'some_function': function () {
            $timeout(function() { ... do something ... }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a service (with requirejs), and my controllers will require it.

Comment: You want to get timeout inside an angular module? then you just need to inject it. If you are outside angular then you could do:- `var timeout = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$timeout')`

Comment: will this apply the scope of my app? (I want to use the angularjs $timeout, because does $scope.apply() implicitly)

Comment: You need to show us more context.

Comment: My domain logic (aka services) are framework agnostic, all services are loaded with requirejs, and when I need to use one of them, I require it, and this service can require my "app" (is an angularjs module instance), and I want to retrieve functionality from this app (so, I want to get the $timeout, and this $timeout will be able to cover the $scope)

Comment: I've updated my question to add an example

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is:

```
app.controller("myCtrl",["$timeout", "otherService" ,function($timeout, otherService){
  $timeout(function() {
        otherService.updateService('Hi');
    }, 3000);
}]);
```